# No se visualiza reporte con Crystal Report en asp.net y C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Estoy tratando de generar un reporte con Crystal Report en Asp.net/C#, el código crea una carpeta y guarda el reporte en pdf, también se visualiza el reporte pero no me muestra nada, el reporte sale en blanco, se guarda vacío y no veo errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```
SqlConnection cnn;
        string connectionString = null;
        connectionString = "data source=***;initial catalog=***;user id=****;password=****;";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        cnn.Open();



        //SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from EstadoCuenta where Usuario='" + usu + "'" + " and NumeroPedido=" + pedido + " Order by Quiebre,OrdenQuiebre", cnn);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from EstadoCuenta where Usuario='jpareja' AND NumeroPedido=4263736   Order by Quiebre,OrdenQuiebre", cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet tablesS = new DataSet();
        adap.SelectCommand = com;            
        adap.Fill(tablesS, "EstadoCuenta");
        cnn.Close();

            ReportDocument crDoc = new ReportDocument();
            crDoc.Load(@"\\Server4rw\Cobranzas\Cobranzas\Reportes\RepEstadoCuentaSQL.rpt");  
            ExportOptions crExportOptions;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions crDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions crFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();

            string strFolder = @"D:\Reportes\EstadoCuenta\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(strFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strFolder);
            crDoc.SetDataSource(tablesS.Tables["EstadoCuenta"]);               
            crDoc.Refresh();

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crDoc;
            crDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = strFolder + "MyPDF.pdf";
            crExportOptions = crDoc.ExportOptions;
            {
                var withBlock = crExportOptions;
                withBlock.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                withBlock.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                withBlock.DestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                withBlock.FormatOptions = crFormatTypeOptions;
            }

            crDoc.Export();           

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo,  creo que esta línea está demás:

```
adap.SelectCommand = com;
```

ya que estás seteando esta propiedad en el constructor del `adapter`.
[SqlDataAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=netframework-4.8#constructores)

1.- Te recomiendo revisar el nombre de la tabla dentro DataSet que está utilizando el reporte. Debería ser *"EstadoCuenta"*

2.- Prueba seteando el DataSet completo en lugar de la tabla. Reemplaza

```
crDoc.SetDataSource(tablesS]);
```

por

```
crDoc.SetDataSource(tablesS.Tables["EstadoCuenta"]);
```

Comment: Ya intenté lo que indicas estimado, pero sigue sin aparecer datos en el reporte.

Comment: Otro motivo por el cual puede pasar es que no coincidan los tipos de datos del DataSet con la Base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Asigna permisos a los usuarios en la carpeta de C:\Windows\Temp, Crystal report. Crea una carpeta allí... muchas veces es causante de mostrar los reportes en blanco.